# ggplot removes all my data when I set x and y limits

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using R to generate a plot from a table.

I used the command `a <- read.table("table.txt")` and that worked fine. When I type "a" it prints out my full table correctly.

I also entered `library(ggplot2)` so I could use ggplot.

Here was my first command:

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=V2, y=V5, group=V7)) + 
   geom_point(size=4, aes(col=V7)) + xlab("Rank") + 
   ylab("Inter-helix angle (Degree)") + 
   opts(legend.position="none")
```

this command generated all the points, but when I added `xlim(0,110) + ylim(0,110)` to the end, it gave me a warning and said "Removed 101 Rows containing missing values" (my table is 101 rows long). The plot that was generated was completely empty. What happened?

Comment: can you paste the output of `dput(a)`?

Comment: I removed the `java` tag and added a `ggplot2` tag since this is a pure R question.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but I thought I should mention that you must be using a somewhat older version of ggplot2, since `opts()` has been deprecated in the current version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing perhaps your data falls out of the ranges you have specified in `xlim` and `ylim` e.g.:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 df <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10)
 ggplot(a, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
 geom_point(size=4) + xlab("Rank") + 
 ylab("Inter-helix angle (Degree)")
```

works fine, but:

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
 geom_point(size=4) + xlab("Rank") + 
 ylab("Inter-helix angle (Degree)") + xlim(0,0.1) + ylim(0,0.1)
```

gives the same error as you get because no values fall between `0` and `0.1`

> Warning message:
>   Removed 10 rows containing missing values (geom_point).

Although without your data this is just the most likely answer.  By the way in general folk tend to use `coord_cartesian`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
 geom_point(size=4) + xlab("Rank") + 
 ylab("Inter-helix angle (Degree)") + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,0.1)) + 
coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,0.1))
```